# C Library checksum for binary file in windows and linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, checksum

I'm using CRC library for checksum, for text file the result same in windows and linux, but for binary file the result different.

I'm using mingw for compiler my c program in windows, checksum result different. is there a way checksum result same between windows and linux using CRC library?

Adding code :

I using this code for checksum file, found it from some web googling. (forgot to save the link).

crc32.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define CRC(crc, ch)     (crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crctabb[(crc ^ (ch)) & 0xff])

static const uint32_t crctabb[256] = {
    0x00000000, 0x77073096, 0xee0e612c, 0x990951ba,
    0x076dc419, 0x706af48f, 0xe963a535, 0x9e6495a3,
    0x0edb8832, 0x79dcb8a4, 0xe0d5e91e, 0x97d2d988,
    0x09b64c2b, 0x7eb17cbd, 0xe7b82d07, 0x90bf1d91,
    0x1db71064, 0x6ab020f2, 0xf3b97148, 0x84be41de,
    0x1adad47d, 0x6ddde4eb, 0xf4d4b551, 0x83d385c7,
    0x136c9856, 0x646ba8c0, 0xfd62f97a, 0x8a65c9ec,
    0x14015c4f, 0x63066cd9, 0xfa0f3d63, 0x8d080df5,
    0x3b6e20c8, 0x4c69105e, 0xd56041e4, 0xa2677172,
    0x3c03e4d1, 0x4b04d447, 0xd20d85fd, 0xa50ab56b,
    0x35b5a8fa, 0x42b2986c, 0xdbbbc9d6, 0xacbcf940,
    0x32d86ce3, 0x45df5c75, 0xdcd60dcf, 0xabd13d59,
    0x26d930ac, 0x51de003a, 0xc8d75180, 0xbfd06116,
    0x21b4f4b5, 0x56b3c423, 0xcfba9599, 0xb8bda50f,
    0x2802b89e, 0x5f058808, 0xc60cd9b2, 0xb10be924,
    0x2f6f7c87, 0x58684c11, 0xc1611dab, 0xb6662d3d,
    0x76dc4190, 0x01db7106, 0x98d220bc, 0xefd5102a,
    0x71b18589, 0x06b6b51f, 0x9fbfe4a5, 0xe8b8d433,
    0x7807c9a2, 0x0f00f934, 0x9609a88e, 0xe10e9818,
    0x7f6a0dbb, 0x086d3d2d, 0x91646c97, 0xe6635c01,
    0x6b6b51f4, 0x1c6c6162, 0x856530d8, 0xf262004e,
    0x6c0695ed, 0x1b01a57b, 0x8208f4c1, 0xf50fc457,
    0x65b0d9c6, 0x12b7e950, 0x8bbeb8ea, 0xfcb9887c,
    0x62dd1ddf, 0x15da2d49, 0x8cd37cf3, 0xfbd44c65,
    0x4db26158, 0x3ab551ce, 0xa3bc0074, 0xd4bb30e2,
    0x4adfa541, 0x3dd895d7, 0xa4d1c46d, 0xd3d6f4fb,
    0x4369e96a, 0x346ed9fc, 0xad678846, 0xda60b8d0,
    0x44042d73, 0x33031de5, 0xaa0a4c5f, 0xdd0d7cc9,
    0x5005713c, 0x270241aa, 0xbe0b1010, 0xc90c2086,
    0x5768b525, 0x206f85b3, 0xb966d409, 0xce61e49f,
    0x5edef90e, 0x29d9c998, 0xb0d09822, 0xc7d7a8b4,
    0x59b33d17, 0x2eb40d81, 0xb7bd5c3b, 0xc0ba6cad,
    0xedb88320, 0x9abfb3b6, 0x03b6e20c, 0x74b1d29a,
    0xead54739, 0x9dd277af, 0x04db2615, 0x73dc1683,
    0xe3630b12, 0x94643b84, 0x0d6d6a3e, 0x7a6a5aa8,
    0xe40ecf0b, 0x9309ff9d, 0x0a00ae27, 0x7d079eb1,
    0xf00f9344, 0x8708a3d2, 0x1e01f268, 0x6906c2fe,
    0xf762575d, 0x806567cb, 0x196c3671, 0x6e6b06e7,
    0xfed41b76, 0x89d32be0, 0x10da7a5a, 0x67dd4acc,
    0xf9b9df6f, 0x8ebeeff9, 0x17b7be43, 0x60b08ed5,
    0xd6d6a3e8, 0xa1d1937e, 0x38d8c2c4, 0x4fdff252,
    0xd1bb67f1, 0xa6bc5767, 0x3fb506dd, 0x48b2364b,
    0xd80d2bda, 0xaf0a1b4c, 0x36034af6, 0x41047a60,
    0xdf60efc3, 0xa867df55, 0x316e8eef, 0x4669be79,
    0xcb61b38c, 0xbc66831a, 0x256fd2a0, 0x5268e236,
    0xcc0c7795, 0xbb0b4703, 0x220216b9, 0x5505262f,
    0xc5ba3bbe, 0xb2bd0b28, 0x2bb45a92, 0x5cb36a04,
    0xc2d7ffa7, 0xb5d0cf31, 0x2cd99e8b, 0x5bdeae1d,
    0x9b64c2b0, 0xec63f226, 0x756aa39c, 0x026d930a,
    0x9c0906a9, 0xeb0e363f, 0x72076785, 0x05005713,
    0x95bf4a82, 0xe2b87a14, 0x7bb12bae, 0x0cb61b38,
    0x92d28e9b, 0xe5d5be0d, 0x7cdcefb7, 0x0bdbdf21,
    0x86d3d2d4, 0xf1d4e242, 0x68ddb3f8, 0x1fda836e,
    0x81be16cd, 0xf6b9265b, 0x6fb077e1, 0x18b74777,
    0x88085ae6, 0xff0f6a70, 0x66063bca, 0x11010b5c,
    0x8f659eff, 0xf862ae69, 0x616bffd3, 0x166ccf45,
    0xa00ae278, 0xd70dd2ee, 0x4e048354, 0x3903b3c2,
    0xa7672661, 0xd06016f7, 0x4969474d, 0x3e6e77db,
    0xaed16a4a, 0xd9d65adc, 0x40df0b66, 0x37d83bf0,
    0xa9bcae53, 0xdebb9ec5, 0x47b2cf7f, 0x30b5ffe9,
    0xbdbdf21c, 0xcabac28a, 0x53b39330, 0x24b4a3a6,
    0xbad03605, 0xcdd70693, 0x54de5729, 0x23d967bf,
    0xb3667a2e, 0xc4614ab8, 0x5d681b02, 0x2a6f2b94,
    0xb40bbe37, 0xc30c8ea1, 0x5a05df1b, 0x2d02ef8d,
};

uint32_t crc32_total = 0;

int crc32(int fd, uint32_t *cval, off_t *clen)
{
    uint32_t lcrc = ~0;
    int nr ;
    off_t len ;
    char buf[BUFSIZ], *p ;

    len = 0 ;
    crc32_total = ~crc32_total ;
    while ((nr = read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
        for (len += nr, p = buf; nr--; ++p) {
        CRC(lcrc, *p) ;
        CRC(crc32_total, *p) ;
    }
    if (nr < 0)
        return 1 ;

    *clen = len ;
    *cval = ~lcrc ;
    crc32_total = ~crc32_total ;
    return 0 ;
}
```

checksum.c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "crc32.c"

int main (int argc,char *argv[]){
        uint32_t val;
        int ch, fd;
        off_t len;
        int (*cfncn)(int, uint32_t *, off_t *);

        cfncn = crc32;
        fd = STDIN_FILENO;
        if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY, 0)) < 0) {
        }
        if (cfncn(fd, &val, &len)) {
        }
        printf("%d\n",val);
}
```

I run this code checksum binary file
Windows result 10992
Linux result 1663

Comment: Hi, i've already edit my question, is there anything wrong ?

Comment: There's still not enough information here to make a good question. But I'll give you a hint: in Linux, opening a file in text or binary mode doesn't matter, but in Windows it makes a big difference.

Comment: did you try to check an external checksumming mechanism? Like md5 which is available for windows (http://www.winmd5.com/) and Linux (md5sum) to check if the files are *really* the same?

Comment: btw: might this be the link? http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/text_cmds/text_cmds-18/cksum/crc32.c

Comment: @xmoex i prefer use code because i will combine it with another project, btw yes the link is right, thanks.

Comment: I found another thing you could try: the site http://hash.online-convert.com/crc32-generator performs crc32-checksum genration for you. You could upload your file to at least determine which one of your implementations works correctly. From this point you can do some debugging for the other one...

Comment: btw: it's not a good idea to include a *.c-File directly!

Comment: And where is the declaration of BUFSIZ???

Answer (score 3):

In Windows, you *must* open the file in binary mode by adding the `_O_BINARY` flag:

```
fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY | _O_BINARY, 0)
```

If you don't, the C++ runtime will perform translations on the contents of the file as it's read in. The most obvious result will be to remove all the `\r` characters from the input, but an even greater danger is that it will signal end-of-file when it reads `\x1a` and you'll stop prematurely. The first is an attempt to normalize the line-endings between text files on the *nix systems where C was first developed (which uses `\n` by itself), and text files on Windows (which uses the pair `\r\n`). The second is backwards compatibility run amok, retaining a convention that existed before DOS when file sizes couldn't be specified in blocks less than 128 characters.

Comment: i try add '_o_BINARY' in windows, i checksum some binary file still different result. should i edit the input before checksum ?

Comment: @rla is there a possibility that the files are not byte-for-byte identical?

Comment: i use the same file for checksum in windows and linux.

Comment: did you verify that the files are the same on windows and linux via an external checksumming method? like md5? just to make sure?

Comment: @xmoex yes, the result same. I use program from your link winmd5 on windows and md5sum on linux.